# Fotorama gallery on pages

Tags: magento2, fotorama-slider

I'm trying to load fotorama on a cms page and some category pages which are custom.

The JS doesn't load on it's own so I thought I was being clever and added this to one of my theme's js files.

```
// my-custom-theme-script.js
requirejs([
    'jquery',
    'fotorama/fotorama'
], function($, fotorama){
});
```

This almost worked. I see my code is causing fotorama to load on the page, but strangely, I'm getting this error in console:

```
Uncaught Fotorama requires jQuery 1.8 or later and will not run without it.
```

So to further debug I changed my theme js to this

```
// my-custom-theme-script.js
requirejs([
    'jquery',
    'fotorama/fotorama'
], function($, fotorama){
    console.log($.fn.jquery); //-> 1.11.0
});
```

So now I'm thinking this is a requiredjs configuration issue on my part. If I add something to the fotorama.js file on about line 98 where the above error comes from, I see that `$` is `false`.

```
// fotorama.js
var JQUERY_VERSION = $ && $.fn.jquery.split('.');

if (!JQUERY_VERSION
    || JQUERY_VERSION[0] < 1
    || (JQUERY_VERSION[0] == 1 && JQUERY_VERSION[1] < 8)) {

    console.log($); //-> false
    throw 'Fotorama requires jQuery 1.8 or later and will not run without it.';
```

How exactly am I suppose to add a custom fotorama gallery to a cms page or block outside of where fotorama is already loading? I'm guessing I'm way off here.

From what I can tell I need to manually define jquery as a dependency in my requirejs-config, however this seems counter intuitive for a js resource that Magento 2 natively includes. Any suggestions?

Comment: Let me know Jamil if you find any answer